# Getting python array assignment issue

Tags: python

I want to save all eat array values to CaloriesConsumed array. But i am getting error 'int' object does not support item assignment on line  CaloriesConsumed[index]=eat[index]. Please help me

```
eat=[2600,2400,3500,3200,2700,3300,3000]
CaloriesConsumed=[]
index=1

while(index<7):
    for CaloriesConsumed in eat:
        CaloriesConsumed[index]=eat[index]
index=index+1
```

Comment: Fixed your indentation, when posting code make it readable for us in the future.

Comment: Why dont you write `CaloriesConsumed = list(eat)`?

Comment: `CaloriesConsumed.extend(eat)`?

Comment: What is the purpose of this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you're going to use indexes like this use a `for` loop instead.

```
for index in range(0, 7):
    CaloriesConsumed[index] = eat[index]
```

And since CaloriesConsumed is empty, you can not access index `0` of the list, this can be achieved by using `append` instead or initiate the list like this `CaloriesConsumed=[0]`, but i'd use append instead:

```
for index in range(0, 7):
    CaloriesConsumed.append(eat[inted])
```

Secondly, you can't do `for CaloriesConsumed in eat` because that replaces your `list` called `CaloriesConsumed=[]`..

And you don't need to iterate over `eat` as you do in your examples since you're using `index`, but if you do want to iterate over `eat` then skip `index` and do the following:

```
for item in eat:
    CaloriesConsumed.append(item)
```

Comment: Note that the first version of the loop will give an `IndexError` because `CaloriesConsumed` starts as an empty list. If you had initialized it with the right number of values (using code like `CaloriesConsumed = [0]*len(eat)`) it would work.

Answer (score 0):

```
CaloriesConsumed.append(eat[index])
```

Comment: Consider adding some details and explanation of how exactly this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont simply try this out :

```
CaloriesConsumed = eat
```

Just make CaloriesConsumed equal to a copy of eat list.

Comment: That's going to create another name for the same list, which may or may not be what is desired.